# Systemctl restart service triggering another command

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I created systemd service, which runs a script that auto-generates some configuration files if these don't exist, and loads the services depending on them, or loads the services with the existing ones.

I would like to provide some extra functionality, allowing the user to clean previous configurations using the same systemctl service.

I thought in **`ExecReload`**, thinking that it would be called when the user types **`systemctl restart service_name`**, but then I discovered that it is not doing what I thought.

Is there a way to do it, please?
I was checking here and in [Freedesktop Systemd doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), but I could not find the way

Comment: You probably need to be creating a systemd _generator_, not a systemd _service_. The _generator_ is a special systemd unit that creates other systemd units.

Comment: Nice, I have to read about that, thank you very much